# Decode Identity-h embedded font text while reading pdf I text7

Tags: itext7

I am working on Itext7 Pdf generation , In the beginning I am setting font with Identity-h embedded . After some point need to read the document content for searching particular text , But not able decode the Decode Identity-h embedded font

Comment: Hi, please attach your code

Comment: Please be aware that before the document is saved, subset embedded fonts cannot be finalized. Thus, trying to read data you just added might fail because your font objects are not fully generated yet.

Comment: @mkl can't we  Decode Identity-h embedded font

Comment: *"can't we Decode Identity-h embedded font "* - probably not before it actually is embedded. While you still are working on the PDF in question, its subset embedded fonts are still not complete.